# Bootstrap table not filling parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason i cannot solve the issue to my problem. I am trying to fill the parent div with the table meaning that the table and the parent are the exact same width and height. I have tried using padding and pull-left and have had no success. Any input?

http://jsfiddle.net/pc1tz5z6/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
            <div class="well">
                <center>
                    <img class="img-circle" src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f7/f72a7e636d1b4831eb3d45cd9bcc893f7fccd8ae_full.jpg" width="120px" height="120px">
                     <h1>Welcome <strong>domkalan</strong> to Ozooma DarkRP</h1>

                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
            <div class="well">
                <div style="padding:0px; padding-left: ; width: 400px;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
            <div class="well">
                <div style="padding:0px; padding-left: ; width: 400px;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url("http://images8.alphacoders.com/374/374665.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.vcenter {
    margin-top: 15%;
}
.well {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 600px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the upper level `div` which has a `.well` class, and that means it has padding in bootstrap.

Adding "`padding:0`" to the `div.well` element will erase the gap between the table and its container.